# Unable to deploy "pubsub" Cloud Function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to deploy a `pubsub` function to run a scheduled backup of my firestore database, but it will not deploy and I cannot figure out why this won't work.

Here is the minimal typescript file with the function that reproduces this behavior:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as key from "../key.json";

export const backupFirestore = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("0 22 * * *")
  .timeZone("America/Los_Angeles")
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    const pk = key.private_key;
    console.log(pk);
  });
```

In my index.ts file I export the function as follows:

```
export { backupFirestore } from "./firestore_backup";
```

Finally, this is my firebase.json:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

I execute `firebase deploy --only "functions:backupFirestore"` and everything looks good and the typescript lint and compiler runs without errors. But the deploy process throws the following error:

> functions: the following filters were specified but do not match any functions in the project: backupFirestore

I also tried running `firebase deploy --only functions` which does not result in an error, but still does not deploy the function.

This is exactly what I am doing for all my other functions, but somehow for the `pubsub` function it fails. This issue has me stunned and I could not find any existing solutions.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to show the [complete, minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.  Don't redact so much that we have to guess at how to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @DougStevenson and apologies. I added the complete code.

Comment: clean your lib folder in the workspace and then try rebuilding the sourcce and before deploying check it manually in the lib folder do you see your function there or not

Comment: And you're saying index.ts contains just that one export line?

Comment: @DougStevenson no it doesn't - there is another 20+ lines that are an exact mirror to the line. I will add a couple to show.

Comment: In order to create a *minimal* example, it would be better if you strip out the irrelevant code, test it in that minimal state, then show the results.  In other words: what is the smallest amount of code you can come up with that reproduces the error?

Comment: can you please, provide `firebase.json`? I suspect you have not added it there

Comment: Hi @hanscl could you please give it a try removing the `const` from your function export? As per the examples in the official documentation - accessible [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) - it doesn't use it and it might be affecting your `export`.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks again for the advice -- I was able to reproduce with the minimal code shown in the updated post. Future posts will be better to begin with :)

Comment: Thanks @gso_gabriel -- I tried using the exports. notation, but no luck either.

Comment: Thanks @Harkal - cleaning the lib alone didn't fix it, but it got me on the right track. See answer!

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the lib folder I discovered the issue. The compiler was writing the `.js` and `.map` files into `lib/src` instead of the `lib` folder -- thus the firebase deploy process was not picking it up.

Upon further research (and creating a minimal code example that reproduces the issue -- thanks @DougStevenson) I found the culprit. The import of an external file from another directory:

```
import * as key from "../key.json";
```

I did have `--outDir` specified for the compiler, but it is the addition of the `--rootDir` option that should resolve this. See: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16683

I opted for solving this by replacing the `import` command with `require`, though that is not the preferred typescript way.
Here is the updated code that generates the output files into `lib` and results in a successful deployment to firebase:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
const key = require("../key.json");

export const backupFirestore = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("0 22 * * *")
  .timeZone("America/Los_Angeles")
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    const pk = key.private_key;
    console.log(pk);
  });
```

Hopefully this is helpful for others coming across this behavior.